How to expose port 3030 in AWS container website?
I have a react project which includes a 'server.js' file which I am going to use to make data requests with important security secrets, at the moment I'm trying to make it work with simple string responses.

When I run both npm start and node src/server/server.js locally, it works great, clicking the 'fetch data' react button makes a request to localhost:3030 (where the server is running) and displays the result.

When I try the same thing on my amazon web service container website, it fails, saying that it failed trying to fetch localhost:3030

How do I fix this so that in my live production AWS instance, I can make api requests to my server.js file ? My code is here:
https://github.com/MartinBarker/aws-react-docker-ghactions
And was built by following this guide on aws container web setup for creating the task / service rules.
https://medium.com/@nwosuonyedikachi/deploying-a-react-app-to-aws-ecs-with-github-actions-5c74c1869800

I think ECS uses EC2. I'd look for EC2 instances in the AWS Console. If you find it, open the EC2 instance, go to Security tab in the bottom, click on the item under Security groups and edit Inbound rules

if you are running your application with port 3030 you should be able to access through exactly with this port and EC2 public IP address also open 3030 port in security groups , it is better to create a target group then register you EC2 instance    to it then create an ALB loadbalancer with listener

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] in plain text?  It looks like your first image file might have a heavily annotated IDE screen shot, replacing that image in particular with code blocks and text will make the question much easier to understand.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

@arjndr ECS uses either EC2 or Fargate, and depending on the ECS network mode setting the ECS docker task may have its own separate Elastic Network Interface (ENI) that has different security groups than the EC2 instance it is running on.
